# Model class for Materialized view cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra

I have created a use table in cassandra 3.0.6 and a Materialized view to list users by city.

```
CREATE TABLE user (
email text,
user_id uuid,
city text,
name text,
password text,
PRIMARY KEY (email, user_id, city)
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW user_by_city AS
SELECT * FROM user
  WHERE email IS NOT NULL AND user_id IS NOT NULL AND city IS NOT NULL         
PRIMARY KEY(city, email, user_id);
```

My question is how can i create a model class for Materialized view in Python

My model class for user table is,

```
 class user(Model):

  __table_name__ = 'user'
  email = columns.Text(primary_key=True)
  user_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True)
  city = columns.Text(primary_key=True)
  name = columns.Text()
  password = columns.Text()
```

How do i create a class for Materialized View similar to this.
I did search on the internet but found that cassandra does not support model class for MV as of now. I want to be 101% sure.

Can someone please confirm ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. You are right! Still MV is not part of Object Mapper

Comment: Thanks chaitan64arun

Comment: Does anyone know is this about to change?